# How do I disable "Highlight new programs" in Windows 10 start menu?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

How do I disable highlighting of new programs in Windows 10?

Here's what I'm talking about:

[image: New apps highlighted in start menu]

What an eyesore.
It's annoying to have to click on each one to get rid of the "New" label, especially since many of them are uninstallers, or READMEs, or links to the program's website.

I thought the "Show recently added apps" option would disable it, but apparently not. Maybe it's only for Metro apps?

[image: Start menu settings]

Anyways, is there any way I can **disable highlighting of new programs in Windows 10's start menu?** A registry hack or something? I'm on Windows 10 x64 build 1511, which is the latest as of 02/14/2016.

<sup><sub>[I'm aware there's already a question asked about this](https://superuser.com/questions/823205/how-do-i-toggle-highlight-newly-installed-programs-on-windows-10-preview), but it deals with Windows 10 Preview, and the solutions don't work on the release version.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the answer you're looking for as it looks like you are using the Metro start-menu, but if you install Classic Shell (http://www.classicshell.net/) there's an option (under General Behavior) to not highlight newly installed programs.

I think this also applies to the Metro menu, but you'd have to use the Classic look of the menu. But that's what I use Classic Shell for any way :)